# Azure ACS retirement in Microsoft 365 - legacy SharePoint REST API impacted?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, api, acs

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/retirement-announcement-for-azure-acs:

> Azure ACS will stop working for new tenants as of November 1st, 2024
> and it will stop working for existing tenants and will be fully
> retired as of April 2nd, 2026.

How will this affect the existing integrations using the legacy SharePoint REST API endpoints? I'm thinking about HTTP requests to SOAP web services (`/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx`) or REST API (`/_api/`).

E.g. Would a request in the browser to the URL [https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')](https://myTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27Documents%27)) still work?

Answer (score 1):

I think these api's will continue to work because they don't authenticate using ACS. Only SharePoint add-in model apps making use of clientid/secret use ACS for authentication. "/_api/" in my opinion is not legacy. We use it a lot.

When opening "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mySite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(%27Documents%27)" in the browser you are being authenticated using oauth.

If you use custom code you have to authenticate another way. We use an Azure AD app registration with a certificate to authenticate against SharePoint online REST api

See this for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins-modernize/from-acs-to-aad-apps#consuming-sharepoint-online-in-app-only-mode-via-an-azure-ad-registered-application